# Performing authentication during testing browserID

Tags: haskell, yesod, browserid

How should I go about performing authentication and authorization during testing for a yesod haskell app? My handlers begin with requireAuth and my authentication plugin is browserID.

So I want to log a user in and do what that handler pertains. Doing this for several handlers.

My code is: https://github.com/urbanslug/payroll-web/tree/development

I have read https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Performing-Authentication-during-Testing but I really don't get it plus it seems outdated since some types like OneSpec are out of scope and aren't on hayoo.

Comment: Did you get the code from that yesod wiki page working and try to modify it for your needs?

Comment: @Codygman I tried to but couldn't get it to work because `doRequest` doesn't seem to exist in the relevant libraries anymore. Also to add to that BrowserID authentication can only be done through JS as far as I can tell so I'd have to find a way to call JS functions from my haskell tests.

Answer (score 2):

The code in that wiki article is now updated.  The details in that code are right for the HashDB authentication plugin, but would need to be modified for BrowserID.